# Changing POST Request to GET to Send a JSON File for Caching

Tags: json, ajax, mongodb, pymongo

How can I modify the following code so it sends a JSON file with the appropriate data?

The reason I ask is because the POST request does not seem to get cached and that's a problem for me. I want to use GET so the JSON file will get cached. Basically what this query does is that it takes the current bounds of the viewport and grabs data from database (MongoDB) based on that.

I tried adding `+ ".json"` before closing the append but it doesn't work.

```
myJSON.append({"type":"Feature","geometry":obj["geometry"],"properties":{"Address":obj["properties"]["Address"],"ID":obj["properties"]["ID"]}})
```

Here's the full code:

```
@app.route('/getData', methods=['POST','GET'])
def getData():
    myCollection = db["myCollection"]
    bBox = [json.loads(request.data)]
    myJSON = []

    for obj in myCollection.find({"geometry":{"$geoWithin": {"$geometry": {"type" : "Polygon" ,"coordinates": bBox}}}},{"properties.Address":1,"properties.ID":1,"geometry":1}):
        myJSON.append({"type":"Feature","geometry":obj["geometry"],"properties":{"Address":obj["properties"]["Address"],"ID":obj["properties"]["ID"]}})

    return jsonify(data = {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":myJSON})
```

On the client-side the AJAX request looks something like this:

```
bounds = getBoundingBox();
$.ajax({
    url: '/getData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(bounds),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        // add data here
    }
});
```

Comment: Get requests usually don't contain a body, the data is usually present in the URL. Are you sure your server is looking for the data in the body for said get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send `JSON` data as a GET parameter and it needs a name

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getData',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {bounds: JSON.stringify(bounds)},
    success: function (data) {
        // add data here
    }
});
```

then on your server side, you retrieve your `bounds` GET parameter and use it for your `json.loads` function.

Comment: So on server side, this line `bBox = [json.loads(request.data)]` should be `bBox = [json.loads(bounds)]`?

Comment: @mapr I am not familiar with your server framework, but I don't think the variable `bounds` just shows up. You should check the documentation on how to retrieve the GET parameter.